# When I create new post with REACT/REDUX the API refresh and don't allow new post after

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I think the title is most explicit for my problem. But I clarify with you.

I have a little project for learning how work REDUX, and I created a little blog with listing all my post I have a counter with the length all my post and I have a component with a form inside for adding a new post.

So, when I go into `FormContainer` (He contain the form), I added some information like title and message I press the validate button, and after that I redirect into `/` (Home) And I can see the new post. But if I click again on `create a new post ?` I create again a new post, the previous post is delete and the current is here.

And I don't understand why... Please check the code inside, If you want more code I can give you.

I using the [JSON PLACEHOLDER API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for request the post.

I created a reducer `Posts-reducer.js`

```js
import {
  FETCH_POSTS,
  ERROR_FETCH_POSTS,
  DELETE_FETCH_POSTS,
  CREATE_POST
} from "../actions/actions-type";

export default (state = [], actions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return actions.payload;
    case ERROR_FETCH_POSTS:
      return actions.error;
    case DELETE_FETCH_POSTS:
      return state.filter(post => {
        if (post.id === actions.payload.id) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
    case CREATE_POST:
      return [...state, actions.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And I created also for each `type action` an action :

```js
import {
  FETCH_POSTS,
  ERROR_FETCH_POSTS,
  ACTIVE_POST,
  DELETE_FETCH_POSTS,
  CREATE_POST
} from "./actions-type";
import axios from "axios";

export function fetch_posts() {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10")
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_POSTS, payload: res.data });
      });
  };
}

export function delete_fetch_posts(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE"
    }).then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: {
          id,
          loading: true
        }
      });
    });
  };
}

export function active_post(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`).then(res => {
      dispatch({ type: ACTIVE_POST, payload: res.data });
    });
  };
}

export function create_post(post) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/", {
        ...post
      })
      .then(res => dispatch({ type: CREATE_POST, payload: res.data }));
  };
}
```

And I would like to show with you my different routes :

```js
class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />
            <Route path="/createpost" component={FormContainer} />
            <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
            <Route path="*" component={RouteNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: in `CREATE_POST`, do you want to combine the arrays? If so, try doing `[...state, ...actions.payload]`, instead of `[...state, actions.payload]`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you clone the existing state then add the new action payload to the cloned version.

This can be done with below.

```
case CREATE_POST: {
    let clonedState = [...state];
    clonedState.push(action.payload);
    return clonedState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but I think I found the problem. This API is a fake API who simulate for example the `post request` and when you using a `post request` the API not save your request on their server and the problem is here.

But, these guys they have building a `json-server` who working in your localhost directly and you can make a real GET,POST,PULL or whatever you want.

So thanks you guys !